# How do I call a function from GameScene in GameViewController using SpriteKit in Swift?

Tags: swift, function, class

I have read countless solutions to the issue and none have worked for me.

In GameScene I have a function

```
func resetBalloon(){

    balloonNode?.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(balloonLocation!, duration: 0.5))


}
```

and in GameViewController I have the code

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
var gameScene = GameScene()
```

followed by

```
func resetID(sender:AnyObject!){ //function is linked to a button
    gameScene.resetBalloon()
    println("all good") //this line runs when the button is pressed

    }
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance for any help I can get.

Comment: Have you verified, that your ballonNode is set, if thats nil then nothing will happen. Try writing a log-statement in the resetBallon() and verify if that is written out.

Comment: I also have called the resetBallon() function on a screen touch which was called in the GameScene and the function does run when the screen is touched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken main role of `GameViewController` is just to present `SKScene`, while the game logic should be in `SKScene`. There can be of course exceptions, but I don't think resetBalloon() is one of them.

So your `GameViewController` could be just this:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
    let skView = view as! SKView
    ...
    skView.presentScene(scene)
  }
}
```

And everything else(even switching to another scene) should be inside `GameScene`.

Comment: Thank you, I knew this was possible but I am currently exploring with SpriteKit for the first time and just trying to establish understanding of how everything works - what I can and can't do.

Comment: No problem, try following some tutorials, e.g. http://www.raywenderlich.com/119815/sprite-kit-swift-2-tutorial-for-beginners (whole website is great source of tutorials), and for further reading check Apple docs as well - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: In other words, you shouldn't be using GameViewController to control objects in a scene class. GameViewController just presents the scene and prepares other minor things unrelated to the control of a scene.